# How to import external JARs in sublime text 2?

Tags: java, jar, import, sublimetext2

Please, excuse me if this is not the proper question to ask here. I'm using sublime text for wiring Java for a while and I really like it, specially, using the *snippets*. All the necessary imports was just fine and I never needed to do anything else. Say, the following imports works just fine,

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.lang.*;
```

However, now I need to write some unit tests and the necessary imports is not working. I get this error message in the Mac console,

[image]

How can I perform the unit tests in Sublime ?

Comment: 'Scrap Sublime and get a proper IDE'

Comment: For large projects, I use eclipse, but, I really admire this editor and would like to know if I can write the unit tests here.

Comment: I don't know Sublime, but you usually add libraries as launch arguments to the compiler. Like `javac -cp bla.jar Foo.java`

Comment: Your errors have absolutely nothing to do with Sublime, they have to do with how you're executing your code - you are obviously missing a config option somewhere (sorry, I don't do Java). Sublime is a glorified text editor - it's great for interpreted languages like Python, and stuff like C or C++, but for Java I'd definitely recommend using an IDE. Sublime just doesn't have the support for it.

Comment: I know obviously I'm missing something :)

Comment: How do you build - what command are you running in that console?